# pass arraylist to overlay class from mapactivity

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, point, google-polyline

I want to pass an arraylist of values from mapactivity to the overlay class:

```
 MyOverlay dataOverlay = new MyOverlay(loc);
```

In the overlay class a constructor is created:

```
public class MyOverlay {

public MyOverlay(List<Double> loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(location.get(1)*1E6) , (int)(location.get(0)*1E6));
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, GeoPoint mp){

     super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, mp);
}
```

}

From this loc arraylist I want to draw one point and mnay polylines from the rest of the values. This geopoint cannot pass to the draw class.

What is the next step after passing and how can I access this loc in the draw method?

Comment: this is my code for drawing point on google map mapctivity class              proj = mapView.getProjection();
          mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        MyOverlay dataOverlay = new MyOverlay(location); 
            mapOverlays.clear();
            mapOverlays.add(dataOverlay);

Comment: and overlay class                                                      public MyOverlay(List<Double> location) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  super();
  this.location = location;
 }

Comment: public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){  super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
   GeoPoint mp = new GeoPoint((int)(location.get(1)*1E6) , (int)(location.get(0)*1E6));
   Point p1 = new Point();  
   mapView.getProjection().toPixels(mp, p1);
 canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.markerblue),p1.x, p1.y , null);   
 }
 private Resources getResources() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 } 
}
       but this is not working my application stops forcefully

Comment: this is my code to draw a path from list of points it dosenot work same error application stops forcefully

Comment: public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView , boolean shadow)
 {
  super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
  Path path = new Path();
  Point p1 = new Point();
  Point startPoint = null, endPoint = null;
  Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
  
  for(int i = 3; i<location.size(); i++)
  {
   GeoPoint point =  new GeoPoint((int)(location.get(i+1)*1E6) , (int)(location.get(i)*1E6));
   projection.toPixels(point, p1);
   if(i==3)
   {
     startPoint = p1;
   path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
   }

Comment: else
   { 
    //endPoint = p1;
    if(i==location.size()-1)
     endPoint = p1;
   path.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
   }   
  }
   Paint paint = new Paint();
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setColor(Color.RED);
         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
         paint.setAlpha(90);
         if (!path.isEmpty())
             canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  
 }

Comment: this is my mapactivity class in which i draw a point                      List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
          Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.markerblue);
          MyItemizedOverlay drawit = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, location);
          
          GeoPoint mp = new GeoPoint((int)(location.get(1)*1E6) , (int)(location.get(0)*1E6));
          OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(mp, "Meeting Point", null);

//            
          drawit.addOverlay(overlayitem);
          mapOverlays.add(drawit);

Comment: hello forum i have added two class one is itemizedoverlay and one overlay itemizedoverlay is for drawing point and overlay is for drawing route but my route cannot displayed my application stops i have uploaded my code

Comment: draw method is not called i added @override also but same error it does not go into draw method